# Express route parsing with regex characters sets

Tags: node.js, regex, express, url-routing, path-to-regexp

Path: `/1,2,3,456,678` - **only numbers and commas**, not anything else
Should be matched with regex-like path like this: `/ids:(\\d+[,\\d]*)` natively
But https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp in express compiles it to some ridiculous regex
Expressers/noders - pls guide me how to approach this right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `*` with `{0,}` solved the issue
So request `/1,2,34,56` matched by path: `/ids:(\\d+[,\\d]{,*})`
Link to `path-to-regexp` issue: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/233